# display query results in data grid view

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms

How to populate the results of my below query in my datagrid box

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you have to explain what are you trying to achieve. Without the description, we can't help you!

Comment: Sorry ...what i need is ..i have connected my access database to the winform app ...now in my second form i want show a table(in data grid box)  after i click the button in my first form , containing only the rows or details of due calibration of fie heads.So how to achieve the same?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to start reading the documentation: [DataGridView Control (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms).

MSDN states:

> The DataGridView control supports the standard Windows Forms data binding model, so it will bind to instances of classes described in the following list:
>
> Any class that implements the `IList` interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
>
> Any class that implements the `IListSource` interface, such as the `DataTable` and `DataSet` classes.
>
> Any class that implements the `IBindingList` interface, such as the `BindingList<T>` class.
>
> Any class that implements the `IBindingListView` interface, such as the `BindingSource` class.

As you can see, you've got several ways to display data in a datagridview control. One of them is to grab data into datatable and then to bind datagridview's `Datatasource` property to that datatable:

```
DataTable dt = AMethodToReturnDataTableObject();
datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
```

**[EDIT]**

In the second form, you have to change constructor:

```
public Sub New(dt As DataTable)
{
    Datagridview1.DataSource = dt
}
```

usage:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = AMethodToReturnDataTableObject()
Using frm As new Form2(dt)
    //wait for user response
    Dim dlg As DialogResult = frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

***Note #1:*** `AMethodToReturnDataTableObject` may look like:

```
Public Function GetDataTable(sql As String, para As OleDbParameter()) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using oConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConn)
        oConn.Open()
        Using oComm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, oConn)
            For Each odp As OleDbParameter in para
                oComm.Parameters.Add(odp)
            Using oRdr As OleDbDataReader = oComm.ExecuteReader()
                dt.Load(oRdr)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

As you can see, above method get a query string and an array of `OleDbParameter`'s. Usage:

```
Dim fromdate As DateTime = New DateTime(1966,1,1)
Dim todate As DateTime = New DateTime(1978,12,31)
Dim ps As OleDbParameter() = New OleDbParameter() _
{
    New OleDbParameter() With {.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = fromdate}, _
    New OleDbParameter() With {.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = todate} _
}

Dim sComm As String = "SELECT Mu.* FROM MyUsers AS Mu WHERE Mu.DateOfBirth BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY Mu.DateOfBirth;"
Dim dt As DataTable = DbHelper.AMethodToReturnDataTableObject(sComm, ps)
```

***Note #2:*** OleDb provider for MS Access database uses un-named parameters. So, the order of parameters is very important!

Good luck!

Comment: Hello ..thank you for your reply ..i have already made a datagrid box containing all the details of the table , now i want to show a datagridbox containing only the query results.

Comment: Please, see updated answer.

Comment: Hello sir ..thank you for you reply but i think you replied with c# and i am using vb.net

Comment: Sorry. The answer contains vb.net code now.